# What is the best way to trigger a php script in laravel through a form button?

Tags: php, laravel, forms, controller, routes

I am using a php script to scrape websites (hQuery by Duzun). I have a form that has an input where someone can paste the URL they want scraped and a submit button to trigger the **scraping**. How can I set up the code below so that when a user clicks submit, the hQuery script picks up the URL they have put in the input and runs the script.

So far I have tried using the action() helper in Laravel to trigger a method in a ScraperController but that doesn't seem to be working. I get an error saying the postScrape method has not been defined.

```
<form action="{{ action('ScraperController@postScrape') }}" method="POST">

route::post('/', 'ScraperController@postScrape');
```

I am hoping that the user can click the button, their URL is passed to the script and it can then scrape the website they have linked to.

Comment: please show us the controller code you tried

Comment: I was planning to have the hquery code in there but based on the response below, that would seem to be the wrong thing to do.

Answer (score 2):

Because scraping is a potentially resource heavy and long-running task, you should delegate this to a queued job. You can read about queues and jobs here: https://laravel.com/docs/master/queues

I'd recommend saving the user's scrape request as a model entry. That way you can track the status (running, errored, completed, etc.), display it in a listing of tasks, attribute system load to users, and so on. Something like `ScrapeTask` (`id`, `user_id`, `url`, `status`, timestamps, and whatever other fields you'll need).

Once you have your model and your queue set up, you will then create a job class. This can be done by running `php artisan make:job ScrapeWebsite`, or you can create it manually.

`app/Jobs/ScrapeWebsite.php`

```php
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use App\ScrapeTask;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class ScrapeWebsite implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /** @var ScrapeTask */
    protected $scrapeTask;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @param ScrapeTask $scrapeTask
     */
    public function __construct(ScrapeTask $scrapeTask)
    {
        $this->scrapeTask = $scrapeTask;

        // also inject any necessary third party libraries, etc.
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        // scrape the website at $this->scrapeTask->url
    }
}
```

Your controller method would look something like this:

`app/Http/Controllers/ScraperController.php`

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Auth;
use App\ScrapeTask;
use App\Jobs\ScrapeWebsite;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ScraperController extends Controller
{
    public function postScrape(Request $request)
    {
        // perform input validation, etc.

        // create a new scrape task
        $scrapeTask = ScrapeTask::create([
            'user_id' => Auth::id(),
            'url'     => $request->input('url'),
        ]);

        // dispatch the ScrapeWebsite job to the queue
        dispatch(new ScrapeWebsite($scrapeTask));

        // redirect to a scrape status monitoring page (or do whatever...)
        return redirect()->route('scrape.monitor', $scrapeTask->id);
    }
}
```

I would highly recommend setting up failed job tracking (https://laravel.com/docs/master/queues#dealing-with-failed-jobs) to make sure that you know when things aren't working.

Comment: This is amazingly helpful! Thank you so much. Plenty to work with here. Really appreciate you taking the time to make such a detailed response.

Comment: Super helpful for me too, Thanks for complete example classes. I wonder if there is a simple queue runner project on github using this approach. The ones I've found are so complicated. Btw. This should be accepted answer imo.